# Kendo Grid Drag and Drop columns function not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

[image: I'm using kendo with ASP.Net MVC4. I've got a problem with grid grouping function. When it load to the **first time, that worked properly**. But after loading next time this problem was occurred.]
    function GetDataSource() {

```
    //PrjKy, PrcsDetKy, PrcsTypKy, AprPrtyKy, AprStsKy, OrginAdrKy, AprUsrKy, NxtActByAdrKy, FrmNxtActDt, ToNxtActDt, FrmInsertDt, ToInsertDt

    var PrjKy = $("#cmbPrjNm").val();
    if (PrjKy == "") { PrjKy = 1; }

    var PrcsDetKy = 1;
    if (PrcsDetKy == "") { PrcsDetKy = 1; }

    var PrcsTypKy = 1;
    if (PrcsTypKy == "") { PrcsTypKy = 1; }

    var AprPrtyKy = 1;
    if (AprPrtyKy == "") { AprPrtyKy = 1; }

    var AprStsKy = 1;
    if (AprStsKy == "") { AprStsKy = 1; }

    var OrginAdrKy = 1;
    if (OrginAdrKy == "") { OrginAdrKy = 1; }

    var AprUsrKy = 1;
    if (AprUsrKy == "") { AprUsrKy = 1; }

    var NxtActByAdrKy = $("#cmbEmployee").val();
    if (NxtActByAdrKy == "") { NxtActByAdrKy = 1; }

    var FrmNxtActDt = $("#rcdDt").val();

    var ToNxtActDt = $("#toDt").val();

    var FrmInsertDt = "";

    var ToInsertDt = "";

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '@Url.Content("~/User/GetAllToDo")',
                data: {
                    'PrjKy': PrjKy,
                    'PrcsDetKy': PrcsDetKy,
                    'PrcsTypKy': PrcsTypKy,
                    'AprPrtyKy': AprPrtyKy,
                    'AprStsKy': AprStsKy,
                    'OrginAdrKy': OrginAdrKy,
                    'AprUsrKy': AprUsrKy,
                    'NxtActByAdrKy': NxtActByAdrKy,
                    'FrmNxtActDt': FrmNxtActDt,
                    'ToNxtActDt': ToNxtActDt,
                    'FrmInsertDt': FrmInsertDt,
                    'ToInsertDt': ToInsertDt
                },
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: '@Url.Content("~/User/UpdateToDo")',
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            },
            create: {
                url: '@Url.Content("~/User/InsertToDo")',
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            },
            destroy: {
                url: '@Url.Content("~/User/DeleteToDo")',
                type: "POST"
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10
    , schema:
    {
        model:
        {
            id: "PrcsDetKy", //Primary key to uniquely identify the row.
            fields: //Relavent fields of the grid should be bind with following model items
                {
                ID: { editable: true, nullable: false },
                AprDtm: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true} },
                AprPrty: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true} },
                AprUsr: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                AprSts: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                AprStsKy: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                AprPrtyKy: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                AprUsrKy: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                AprResnKy: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                PrjId: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                TaskId: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                TaskNm: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true} },
                PrcsDetKy: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                TaskTyp: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true} },
                PrcsTypKy: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                PrjKy: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                PrcsDetAprKy: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                PrjNm: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true} },
                Des: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true} },
                NxtActByAdr: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true} },
                NxtActByAdrKy: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                NxtActDt: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                Rem: { editable: true, nullable: true, type: "string" },
                OriginBy: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                Hyperlinks1: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                Hyperlinks2: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                Hyperlinks3: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                Hyperlinks4: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                OrginAdrKy: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                WrkStnKy: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                ObjKy: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                ObjCd: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                ObjNm: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                ItmKy: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                ItmCd: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                IsAct: { editable: true, nullable: true },
                IsApr: { editable: true, nullable: true }
            }
        }
    }
    });

    return dataSource;
}


function LoadGridView() {

    var dataSource = GetDataSource();

     $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        editable: "inline",
        selectable: "row",
        toolbar: ["create"],
        autobind: true,
        reorderable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100]
        },
        sortable: {
            mode: "multiple"
        },
        sort: { field: "PrjNm", dir: "asc" },
        groupable: {
            messages: {
                empty: "Drop columns here"
            }
        },
        columnMenu: {
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            messages: {
                columns: "Hide/Show Columns",
                filter: "Apply filter",
                sortAscending: "Sort (asc)",
                sortDescending: "Sort (desc)"
            }
        },
        resizable: true,
        dataBinding: function () {
            record = (this.dataSource.page() - 1) * this.dataSource.pageSize();
        },
        filterable: {
            messages: {
                and: "And",
                or: "Or",
                filter: "Apply filter",
                clear: "Clear filter",
                info: "Filter by"
            },
            extra: true, // show extra filters
            operators: { // redefine the string operators
                string: {
                    contains: "Contains",
                    doesnotcontain: "Doesn't contain",
                    startswith: "Starts With",
                    endswith: "Ends"
                },
                number: {
                    eq: "Is Equal To",
                    neq: "Not equal to",
                    gte: "Greater than or equal to",
                    lte: "Less than or equal to",
                    gt: "Greater than",
                    lt: "Less than"
                }
            }
        },
        navigatable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "ID", title: "Ref#", template: "#= ++record #", width: "50px" },
            {
                field: "AprDtm",
                title: "Record Date",
                editor: function (container, options) {
                    var model = options.model;
                    $('<input id="DtTxt" name="' + options.field + '" data-value-field="' + options.field + '" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" data-format="' + options.format + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoDatePicker({
                        change: function (e) {
                            model.set("AprDtm", e.sender._oldText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                format: "{0: MM-dd-yyyy}"
            },
            {
                field: "PrjNm",
                title: "Project",
                width: "150px",
                editor: function (container, options) {
                    var model = options.model;
                    $('<input id="btntxt" name="' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoComboBox({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "POST",
                            transport: {
                                read: '@Url.Content("~/User/GetProjectList")'
                            }
                        },
                        change: function (e) {

                            combo = e.sender;
                            selectedItm = combo.select();
                            dataItem = combo.dataItem(selectedItm);

                            model.set("PrjKy", dataItem.PrjKy);
                            model.set("PrjNm", dataItem.PrjNm);
                        },
                        dataValueField: "PrjKy",
                        dataTextField: "PrjNm"
                    });
                }
            },
            { field: "TaskNm", title: "Task Name", width: "150px" },
            {
                field: "Des",
                title: "Description"
            },
            {
                field: "TaskTyp",
                title: "ToDo Type",
                width: "110px",
                editor: function (container, options) {
                    var model = options.model;
                    $('<input id="cmbPrsTyp" name="' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoComboBox
                            ({
                                dataSource: {
                                    type: "POST",
                                    transport: {
                                        read: '@Url.Content("~/User/GetProjectTypeList")'
                                    }
                                },
                                change: function (e) {

                                    combo = e.sender;
                                    selectedItm = combo.select();
                                    dataItem = combo.dataItem(selectedItm);

                                    model.set("PrcsTypKy", dataItem.CdKy);
                                    model.set("TaskTyp", dataItem.CdNm); // Once this model updated it will aper in the grid column too

                                    return false;
                                },
                                dataValueField: "CdKy",
                                dataTextField: "CdNm"
                            });
                }
            },
            {
                field: "AprPrty",
                title: "Piority",
                width: "100px",
                editor: function (container, options) {
                    var model = options.model;
                    $('<input id="cmbPrsTyp" name="' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoComboBox
                            ({
                                dataSource: {
                                    type: "POST",
                                    transport: {
                                        read: '@Url.Content("~/User/GetPiorityList")'
                                    }
                                },
                                change: function (e) {
                                    combo = e.sender;
                                    selectedItm = combo.select();
                                    dataItem = combo.dataItem(selectedItm);

                                    model.set("AprPrty", dataItem.CdNm);
                                    model.set("AprPrtyKy", dataItem.CdKy);

                                    return false;
                                },
                                dataValueField: "CdKy", //value member of the combobox Eg: 8645
                                dataTextField: "CdNm"//display member of the combobox Eg: Hight
                            });
                }
            },
            {
                field: "NxtActByAdr",
                title: "Act By",
                editor: function (container, options) {
                    var model = options.model;
                    $('<input id="usr" name="' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoComboBox
                            ({
                                dataSource: {
                                    type: "POST",
                                    transport: {
                                        read: '@Url.Content("~/User/GetEmployeeList")'
                                    }
                                },
                                change: function (e) {
                                    combo = e.sender;
                                    selectedItm = combo.select();
                                    dataItem = combo.dataItem(selectedItm);

                                    model.set("NxtActByAdr", dataItem.AdrNm);
                                    model.set("NxtActByAdrKy", dataItem.AdrKy);

                                    return false;
                                },
                                dataValueField: "AdrKy",
                                dataTextField: "AdrNm"
                            });
                },
                width: "150px"
            },
            {
                field: "NxtActDt",
                title: "Next Act Date",
                editor: function (container, options) {
                    var model = options.model;
                    $('<input id="NxActDtTxt" name="' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoDatePicker({
                        change: function (e) {
                            model.set("NxtActDt", e.sender._oldText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                format: "{0: MM-dd-yyyy}",
                width: "110px"
            },
            { field: "Rem", title: "Remarks" },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "", width: "180px" }
        ]
    });

}


$("#btnLoadGrid").click(function () {
    LoadGridView();
});
```

I'm using kendo with ASP.Net MVC4. I've got a problem with grid grouping function. When it load to the **first time, that worked properly**. But after loading next time this problem was occurred.

Please help me to solve this problem..........................................
.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1):

Even I had faced an issue with drag and drop working first time and not after that. The solution was to reset the grid view or list view that you have. Call the destroy function on the KENDO control and create it again.

Comment: Here's a code example:

        kendo.destroy(document.getElementById("divReport"));